# Проблема с классами

Tags: c++, ооп, классы, указатели

Допустим у меня есть класс TTable с конструктором TTable (TRow это другой класс, с ним все работает)

```
class TTable
{   
public:
    TTable(TRow *R, int max);
    TRow *Rpointer;
}
```

Реализация конструктора

```
TTable::TTable(TRow *R, int max)
{
    setMax(max);
    Rpointer = R;
}
```

В главном методе я вызываю его и передаю значения

```
int main()
{
    int max = 0;
    cin >> max;
    TRow *row;
    row = new TRow[max];
    TTable table(row, max);
}
```

Далее у меня есть класс TProcessor

```
class TProcessor
{
public:
    TProcessor(TTable *T);
    TTable *Tpointer;
};
```

Реализация

```
TProcessor::TProcessor(TTable *T)
{
    Tpointer = T;
}
```

Я хочу вызвать его в главном методе

```
TProcessor processor();
```

В качестве аргумента должен быть указатель, который я обьявляю вот так:

```
TTable *tab;
tab = new TTable;
```

Таким образом я создаю новый. но как мне сделать указатель на этот 
TTable table(row, max); который был вызван сразу в главном методе?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваш `TTable` находится в переменной `table`. Следовательно....

```cpp
TTable table(row, max);
TProcessor processor(&table);
```

...символ `&` означает, что мы передаем не значение переменной, а её адрес, который используется в указателе.

Comment: Огромное спасибо. Помогли!